# How to add to browser autocomplete history for a search input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, tampermonkey

A `<input type="search">` element will remember the search history for anything submitted across all domains as long as the `name` attribute matches. Apparently this only adds to the list when there is a `submit` event on a form.

I am working on a TamperMonkey script for a site that has has this search element but does it's form submission via JS. I want to make my script add a `name="whatever"` attribute (easy enough), but **how can I get it to add an item to the browser autocomplete history without a real form submission?**

See this example that uses common name attributes and you will probably see some searches you performed on other sites.

```html
<input type="search" name="q" placeholder="name='q'">
<br><br>
<input type="search" name="query" placeholder="name='query'">
<br><br>
<input type="search" name="search" placeholder="name='search'">
```

The autocomplete looks like this:

[image]

Comment: *how can I get it to add an item to the browser autocomplete history without a real form submission* <-- You don't. Autocomplete is completely handled by the user agent. All you can do is use the `autocomplete` attribute on form elements to enable the feature for use, but you cannot set up what the values will be.

Comment: @ScottMarcus So is the way it works in the browser is when a form submits it will save the value? I suppose there's no way I can mock that?

Comment: Correct, except that browsers don't store all input. Only ones with common names. You can create your own implementation of autocomplete through the use of arrays and CSS.

Comment: Have you considered using a [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)?

Comment: @mykaf Yes, but then I'd have to store data and provide a UI to remove items from that list. The default way the browser handles this, that's all just taken care of for you. For what this is for I will probably skip doing this for now. Too much work for not enough benefit. I was hoping there would be a simple way to just hook into this and enable it, but without this it's not worth doing for just a little script that makes a few UI enhancements

Answer (score 0):

you don't. Form submission needs to happen to add value to autocomplete.

You can always use a select or input instead with your predefined values.
I would use some free open source library like [forms.js](https://formsjs.io/)

This is how I might approach this issue with the forms.js library, this way you can select something from a predefined list and also create your own value if it is not in the list.

```css
body{
background: #eee
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@forms.js/core/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select/dist/css/tom-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="form"></section>
<script type="module">
import { Form } from "https://esm.sh/@forms.js/core";

const form = new Form("form", {
  id:"form",
  schema: [
    {
      id: "search",
      type:"select",
      label: "Search:",
      optionsList:[
        {
          value: "front-end",
          label: "front-end",
        },
        {
          value: "angular",
          label: "angular",
        }
      ],
      options: {
        persist: false,
          createOnBlur: true,
          create: true
      }
    }
  ]
});
</script>
```